# Extend angular.js to automatically append a postfix to all templateURL values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a lot of angular.js components, that load html templates in a typical way :

```
templateUrl: 'www.me.com/view.html'
```

I'd like to, somehow adjust/extend angular.js, to always append certain string to the templateURL, before it is accessed. For example, such that in the above example, the actual uri that will be fetched will be :

```
www.me.com/view.html?a=b&c=d
```

not

```
www.me.com/view.html
```

I know I could simply edit the component files to append this ?a=b&c=d at the end, but I am not able to do so. I can however, add a javascipt file to the website that would somehow accomplish this.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use an HTTP interceptor. If your URLs uniquely identity the template before adding the query parameters, this will work.

HTTP interceptors allow you to decorate HTTP requests and responses with additional data.

Here's an example of how that might look:

```
function templateInterceptor() {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            if (config.url.indexOf('www.me.com/view.html') === 0) {
                config.params = config.params || {};
                config.params.a = 'b';
                config.params.c = 'd';
            }

            return config;
        }
    }
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('templateInterceptor', templateInterceptor)
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('templateInterceptor');
    });
```

The line `if (config.url.indexOf('www.me.com/view.html') === 0)` depends on some reliable way of determining if the URL refers to a template. *Maybe filtering requests for .html files would be more accurate.*

The reason this only works if your URLs uniquely identify each template prior to the query parameters being appended is because of the AngularJS template cache. AngularJS uses the `templateUrl` to cache requests for templates.

If this solution does not work you may be forced to fork AngularJS and make the change in the template cache code.